# Prevent install for specific manufacturer-API combination

Tags: android, android-manifest

We use a 3rd party SDK that crashes 100% of the time on Asus devices running Android 7.0 (we can't get rid of the SDK). The same device running 7.1 will not crash. I know I can block specific devices using the Google Play Developer Console, but I'd rather not block the devices since there's a chance that they either haven't updated to 7.0, or they have been updated to 7.1.

I asked Google Play support if there was something I was missing in the console, and they said it's not possible to block a manufacturer-API combination from the dev console. However, they said there was a way to do so using the manifest, but that they weren't qualified to tell me exactly how. I haven't been able to find any information on this. The docs mention how to declare restricted screen support using the manifest, but nothing about a manufacturer.

Does anybody know a way to accomplish this using the manifest?

Comment: does the crash happen immediately when the app opens or when you call a method in the 3rd party SDK?

Comment: It happens when we manipulate a view from the SDK. It throws a signal 11 (SIGSEGV). It's a core piece of functionality for our app. We're looking into new SDKs, but that will be months of work.

Comment: Ok.. Then on your SplashActivity, or the first activity, check
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE.equals( "7.0.0") && android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("Asus") ){
    // tell user that app is not available in their current sdk version. Ask them to update maybe.
// close activity
}

Comment: That's what I was planning to do as a last resort if the download can't be prevented. Thank you.